# opening pdf documents in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf

i need a free control for my asp.net pages which would display pdf documents,so that the client can view pdf files without the need of installing any pdf. i tried searching in google but all i get is for windows application.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean allow viewing PDFs on clients without a PDF reader plug-in installed?

I'm researching a related topic and come across this same question asked and answered here on SO:

[PDF viewer on the .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593669/pdf-viewer-on-the-net/1597886#1597886)

I provided an answer to a component I found on CodeProject.  Check it out if you're still interetsed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to convert the pdf's to something a browser without acrobat reader could display.

Try [Dynamic PDF Rasterizer for .NET](http://www.cete.com/Products/DynamicPDFRasterizerforNET/).