# PDF viewer on the .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have many pdf files in my project so I need it available to view for any client so I tried to give it as link in JS and it's worked but when I tried with a machine doesn't have the adobe PDF Reader it gives it as a link to download so any body can help me by giving me a **free** tool,library,JQuery,JScriipt,ActiveX...etc just for viewing PDF not for editing that worked on both firefox and IE8???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is strictly not programming related. You need a Pdf reader on the client to be able to view Pdf documents.

Follow the links and install. There should be plugins to read Pdf documents for all known browsers.

On the other hand. If you want to convert your Pdf documents to html text you could check out [Pdf to Html](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net)

Comment: thnx a lot Makach thats help me a lot but also I need to create a thumnail with free tool from pdf file's first page can u help me??

Comment: Maybe you could ask that as a separate question instead:) You could also just use a standard pdf/image icon for the html and use a descriptive text.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at this article:

[ASP.NET PDF Viewer User Control Without Acrobat Reader Installed on Client or Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/aspnetpdfviewer.aspx)

There's a [GoogleCode page](http://code.google.com/p/pdfvieweraspnet/) for it with a fair amount of activity.

I haven't tried the code but might for an upcoming project.  No word in the article regarding browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this helps or not. But take a look at this

[Meet iPaper
The best document viewing experience on the web](http://www.scribd.com/ipaper)

> iPaper is a rich document format built
>   for the web. Built with Adobe Flash,
>   iPaper will display documents in the
>   same way regardless of whether you're
>   using Windows, MacOS, or Linux. Your
>   readers no longer have to download
>   files or extra software to view your
>   documents.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a link to the Adobe Reader download page below the links to your PDFs, and a message to tell users to download Reader if they don't have it.