# Quick & Easy PDF Viewer Ideas

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, jquery

This question has been asked several times but my situation is a little different.

I have a web application written in C# where I get a string value passed to this page I'm working on.  This string value represents a filename of a PDF file I need to display on this page.  I'm supposed to have a left panel where I have some information displayed, and a right panel showing the contents of a PDF file.  I'm using a simple table here to separate the panels.  All PCs should already have Acrobat Reader installed.

My question is simple.  How can I display the contents of the PDF file within this table?  I don't need anything fancy.  It has to be **free** and **simple** enough for a newbie like me to set up.  It could even be written in jQuery/AJAX, if there even is a way.

I've looked at a Webbrowser control within an ASP.NET page, but it looks way too complicated for a simple viewer.  I looked at Webparts, but I'm not sure if that's doable in a non-Sharepoint environment.  Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure what the constraints are, but you if you put an iFrame in a table cell (or anywhere), and set it's source to the PDF document, assuming they have a PDF viewer plugin in their browser, it will just work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF viewer on the .net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593669/pdf-viewer-on-the-net)

Comment: I dont know how it is not related to other questions here. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593669/pdf-viewer-on-the-net and it has links to .net libraries.

Comment: @jamietre - Thanks. I've been having trouble with iFrame and Object using IE7. Demos work online, so it must be something I'm doing.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to be displaying test PDFs on my LOCAL drive. Showing a PDF off the Internet works perfectly.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `object` tag?  More ideas are here [Make PDF display inline instead of separate Acrobat Reader window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859815/make-pdf-display-inline-instead-of-separate-acrobat-reader-window)

Comment: It's been a long time since I've been on my StackOverflow account, but I remember this response helped me.  Thanks and sorry for taking so long.